# How can I get .text section from PE file using pefile

Tags: python, python-2.7, portable-executable

How can I get the content of `.text` section (or any other section) from PE by using `pefile` module?

Comment: Voted to reopen. This seems to be a perfectly valid question, with the possibility of valid answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sections` attr of PE class instance is sections list and each item have get_data function:

```
>>> import pefile
>>> pe = pefile.PE('./psfile.exe')

>>> for section in pe.sections:
...   print (section.Name, hex(section.VirtualAddress),
...     hex(section.Misc_VirtualSize), section.SizeOfRawData )
... 
('.text\x00\x00\x00', '0x1000', '0xd3e4', 57344)
('.rdata\x00\x00', '0xf000', '0x5504', 24576)
('.data\x00\x00\x00', '0x15000', '0x3684', 8192)
('.rsrc\x00\x00\x00', '0x19000', '0x444', 4096)
```

10 first bytes from text section data for example:

```
>>> pe.sections[0].get_data()[:10]
'\x81\xec\x90\x00\x00\x00j>\x8dD'
```

Comment: Why `section.Name` shows this hex output, too? `'\x00\x00\x00'` Would be great to better understand if you might show me a way how to remove this. Is there a way to do it with using the pefile tools?

Comment: @webtobesocial im dont know why, but you can use `rstrip` to get rid of '\x00': `'.text\x00\x00\x00'.rstrip('\x00')` will return just `.text`

Comment: @ndpu how can i jsonfy that in python..... like the output ...

Comment: @omah94 didn't understand your question, there is standard json lib, check docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: so i found a way to do this after reading the documentation....i will share with you once i am done

Comment: '.text\x00\x00\x00'.replace('\x00','') will return .text as well

Comment: @b00r00x0 It's the `byte` class formatted when printing.